# Error in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, datetime, where-clause

I've created a view with 2 columns, here's the code of my view:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(DATETIME, a.ValorF) AS FechaCumplimiento
  ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), a.FlowID) AS FlowID
   FROM (SELECT fd.ValorF
    ,fd.FlowID
    FROM Qflow.dbo.FlowData fd 
    INNER JOIN Qflow.dbo.Flows f 
        ON fd.FlowID = f.FlowID
    WHERE ValorF IS NOT NULL
    AND f.TemplateID = 1211 AND fd.DataID = 8) a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  CAST(
  REPLACE
  (REPLACE
  (REPLACE
  (REPLACE
  (REPLACE
  (f.Value,'<Vs>',''),'<V>',''),'</V>',''),'</Vs>',''),'Z','')AS DATETIME) AS FechaCumplimiento
   , f.FlowID
   FROM (SELECT 
   fs.Value
  ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), fs.FlowID) AS FlowID 
  FROM [Qflow3].[dbo].[FlowData] fs
    INNER JOIN [Qflow3].[dbo].[TemplateData] t
        ON fs.TemplateDataID = t.TemplateDataID
  WHERE fs.FlowID IN (SELECT fi.FlowId
                      FROM Qflow3.dbo.Flow fi
                      WHERE TemplateID = '2EA13351-7838-4BAF- A6CD-B768688F4C47') 
AND t.Name = '_FECHACUMPLIMIENTO'
AND t.Description = 'Recomendacion') f
```

And now I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(f.FechaCumplimiento) AS Anio
FROM [dbo].[vi_CAR_FecCumplimiento] f
WHERE YEAR(f.FechaCumplimiento) = 2010
ORDER BY f.FechaCumplimiento ASC
```

But I'm getting this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've trying a lot of changes in my view and in my query but it seems not to work.

Comment: Try taking out the conversion to DATETIME and see if you don;t have some values that aren't valid DATETIME values.

Comment: Is there any varchar data that converts to a NULL datetime or has invalid datetime values after your REPLACES? If so, the view might compile, but you will have issues even querying the view, since the view will run its CAST before you have filtered it on 2010.

Comment: In my view I'm converting from xml to varchar a then replace xml tags, but there's no null values in both tables.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: That view was created in another database(CARII), and I'm running my query in that database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CARII, is that a MySQL variant or some other such thing?   Also, does `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vi_CAR_FecCumplimiento]` return the same error?

Comment: CARII is the name of the database where my view is stored. when I run select * from vi_CAR_FecCumplimiento it returns all values ok

Comment: That query was for a report, but I made some logic on ssrs and solved my problem. Thanks!